# Send an empty array in a querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, query-string

I know there isn't a standard about arrays in querystring and you can use several notations for the same results, so I'm focusing highly on ASP.Net notation.

Is there a way to send an empty array as a parameter to a webAPI controller?
I used jQuery's  internal function [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) that serializes data for querystrings to see how they notate the empty array but **jQuery simply ignores the empty array**!

```
$.param({emptyArr: [], age:22}) // age=22"
```

So, is there a way of sending empty array to a .Net service?

Comment: Sending nothing is not a viable option because we want to provide in the service 

1. Use the default values - send nothing- null. 
2. Send your own array to override the default. 
3. Send an empty array so no value will be used, not the default nor the user's.

Comment: But, why would you want to send an empty array?

Comment: @NewAmbition, did you read my comment just above yours...?

Comment: Was you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Sisir, I'm no longer active on this website because of their management. Truly sorry.